# How do I use JSON with U2/Universe

Tags: universe, u2, unidata

U2/Universe JSON document have the following UDOSetProperty, how would one set the value if it has multiple values?  For example if I have multiple emails.

example:  UDOSetProperty(udoHandle, "to", value)

```
 "to": [
        {
            "email": "recipientEmail@example.com",
            "name": "Recipient Name",
            "type": "to"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you are trying to add another "to" array element or if you want to add a 2nd "email" only.

So working with your example:

```
"to": [
        {
            "email": [ "recipientEmail@example.com",
            "name": "Recipient Name",
            "type": "to"
        },
        {
            "email": [ "recipient2Email@example.com",
            "name": "Recipient2 Name",
            "type": "to"
        }
 ],
```

If you wanted to create the above JSON from scratch, with the UDO commands, the steps would be:

Using the following functions should help you with what you are trying to do:

1. Create the initial/root object         UDOCreate(UDO_OBJECT,
   udoHandle)
2. Create the array                       UDOCreate(UDO_ARRAY,
   thisArray)
3. ( Use UDOCreate and UDOSetProperty to create the theEmailObject you
   want to add to the array, and then add it to the object with
       UDOArrayAppendItem( thisArray, theEmailObject )
4. Then add the array to the root object eith  UDOSetProperty(udoHandle,
   "TO", thisArray)

Note the part that is important is that there are several functions for dealing with arrays.

Mike

Created a program that builds the JSON with the U2 UDO functions, and added it to github:
https://github.com/RocketSoftware/multivalue-lab/blob/master/U2/Demos/UDO/JSON/The-Basics/arrayExample

Comment: Quick question Mike, the UDOSetProperty, all it does is escaping a string by insert \ before the " right?  So basically, anywhere it sees the " this will become \", Is that correct?

Comment: To be honest, I have not checked to see if there were other characters that are escaped.  Yet you are correct about the '"' becoming '\"' when written out to a JSON string.